# @Value not getting the value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

im trying to get a value from the application.properties in a Spring boot app.

The class is defined with the tag @Component, I already tried @Service too, and with
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") and without the @PropertySource but in any case they get the value.

```
   @Component
   @PropertySource("application.properties")
    public class TerraformOutput implements IPatternOutput {

    @Value(value = "${terraformPath}")
    private String pathTerraform;
}
```

The interface is defined like this

```
@Component
public interface IPatternOutput extends IOutput {
    
    String createFile(TerraformTemplate t);
}
```

And the superior interface

```
@Component
public interface IOutput {

    void deleteFile(String path);

}
```

In any case I tried without implementing the interface but it didn´t get it in any case

The application.properties is defined in this way:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbcloudbatch?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
terraformPath=C:/terraform-files/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First: check if your application reads your application.properties file. Does it read other properties from that file? If No: try to break your aplication.properties file, see if the application starts. If it starts - it does not read the file. If Yes: is your service in @ComponentScan scope?

Comment: Hi @user2706534 it reads from application.properties, but in this file exactly not. How does ComponentScan exactly to check if its in the scope. Thanks

Comment: how did you defined terraformPath in your application.properties file?

Comment: Hi @IssaKhodadadi i just edited to put the application.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `@PropertySource` annotation goes together with `@Configuration` annotation for your configuration class. It works for entire project. So, place it with your configuration and then in any class that is annotated as `@Component`, `@Service` `@Controller` etc you can use `@Value` annotation exactly the way you showed in your code. Here is a good article on the issue: [Properties with Spring and Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)

Comment: Hi Michael, first thanks for your answer. If I dont have any @Configuration File? How can it be solved?

Comment: First, its a good idea to have a configuration file. But here is an article about how to use @PropertySource: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue in your shared code. However, it is possible you override the *terraformPath* in somewhere. Spring Boot considers specific orders of externalized config files. It is well explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) already.